# Why dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using Xcode8.1 and when I run project in my computer I get error but The Project runs finely where I have brought to develop.

Sorry for representational error

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
    0x10df27000 <+0>: int3   
->  0x10df27001 <+1>: nop
```

and Log Screen shows

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ImageOpenTransition.framework/ImageOpenTransition
      Referenced from: 

    /Users/parallaxlogic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/312028A8-3181-4CAA-8CFD-1AEC47B8A346/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3DE92181-085B-4028-B6CD-34B55DFB9781/Awake.app/Awake
          Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:


    /Users/parallaxlogic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/312028A8-3181-4CAA-8CFD-1AEC47B8A346/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3DE92181-085B-4028-B6CD-34B55DFB9781/Awake.app/Frameworks/ImageOpenTransition.framework/ImageOpenTransition: required code signature missing for 

    '/Users/parallaxlogic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/312028A8-3181-4CAA-8CFD-1AEC47B8A346/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3DE92181-085B-4028-B6CD-34B55DFB9781/Awake.app/Frameworks/ImageOpenTransition.framework/ImageOpenTransition'
```

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue occurred to my project before. I fixed by add missing framework the the build target. 
First, select your app target and go to general page then find Embedded binaries.
[image]
Try to add your missing framework "**ImageOpenTransition**" in it.
This method solved my problem. Hope it can help you.